# Push Notification in Swift from JSON file

Tags: php, json, swift, apple-push-notifications, push

I have created an push notification and I have connected it to firebase. When the I send a notification from firebase it runs smoothly in foreground, background etc. When I try to send a modified json file as a push notification it doesn't come. How can I fix it?

Comment: If you are referring to the Firebase admin panel did you try using "Custom Data" under the "Additional Options" when sending a push notification? Or are you trying to send this from a server?

Comment: I tried sending notification from Cloud Messaging and it worked. When I try to send a costum one from my server (using json file) it doesn't work

Comment: Doesn't work is very hard to understand why without a little code example. Maybe try posting what json you are trying to send.

Comment: I am posting the php code that I send the notification from. Although I have modified the default structure and I have customised it to my needs. When I send this structure it just comes to console but it doesn't show in the application in iphone.

Comment: <?php
 define('G_FIREBASE_SMS_KEY', '');
 $firebase_uid = '';

 $data  = array(
     'notification_id'   => rand(11111111, 99999999),
     'notification_token' => 'TokenSistemi',
     'notification_title' => 'Hi',
     'notification_body'  => 'Something new.',
     'notification_details' => '{"app_frame": "homeScreen"}'

Comment: $headers = array (
     'Authorization: key=' . G_FIREBASE_SMS_KEY,
     'Content-Type: application/json'
    );
 #Send Reponse To FireBase Server 
 $ch   = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, 'https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send');
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, true);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
 $result  = curl_exec($ch);
 curl_close($ch);
 echo $result;
?>

Comment: Oh man. Thats hard to read. Can you edit your answer instead and place this inside there? Also, show the outputed json.

Comment: Please check out the code : https://prnt.sc/qnxppo